# Call Get-ADComputer in a loop until the object is found

Tags: powershell

I want to call Get-ADComputer from Powershell in a loop until the computer object is created in Active Directory.

I'm using the following code. The script won't loop. How can I write the code so it loops correctly?

```
    do {(Write-Host "." -nonewline -ForegroundColor Red),(sleep 3)}
    until(Get-ADComputer -name ComputerName)
```

I can't figure out what's missing. I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -Filter parameter, with the Name parameter you get a terminating error in case the computer in question cannot be found.

```
do {
  Write-Host "." -nonewline -ForegroundColor Red
  sleep 3      
} until(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq 'ComputerName'})
```